# firefox css style sheet not loading

Tags: css, firefox

It is just really bizarre that linked css to my local host was not loading with Firefox. It kept using the style sheet from yesterday while everything else loaded right. I tried to restart the browser, the Apache PHP server, neither worked. But it is working with Chrome. Maybe I need to clean the cache?

```
 <link type="text/css" media="all" href="files/back_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Hard refresh your firefox browser pageload, with CTRL + F5 keys when focused on the offending tab.

Comment: just cleared cache, firefox is working again. still puzzled why it only affected the style sheet loading but not the others.